# Write back functionality is not working in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I have created a writeback template file and added few additional columns to the existing update and insert section. When I'm trying to update the fields, they are reverting back to the original value in my case it's null. Same functionality is working fine in QA. I'm facing this issue only in Production environment. Can someone please help me out.

I have given all permissions to the BI consumer role and enables writeback for these columns in RPD and BI catalog page. Placed writeback XML in all custom messages folders and restarted the BI servers

Answer (score 1):

As you say yourself, it works in QA. Therefore the thing is that you have to start comparing your environments. Also don't forget to verify if the database user is allowed to write: QA DB users can easily have more privileges than a user on a prod DB.
But because it works in QA, you know that the issue is somewhere in your configuration of the prod environment.